# Is it possible to allow Gson to just skip fields with wrong types?

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I have a class from an SDK that I don't have access to change, but that I would like to serialize a JSON-valid string into.

However, an external API sometimes puts in the wrong type for a Date field.

**Long story short: Can I just ignore errors in GSON, or tell Gson to ignore errors on fields, and just get the partial object?**

For example, the field should be a double, but I get a Date(number) instead. But I'm not using it anyway, so I don't care, and I don't need the whole process to fail. I just want the parcable fields out, with the faulty fields left null.

NOTE: Writing a deserializer that creates the object I want to have created by Gson defeats the very purpose I propose.

This i a line of code that fails, because a single field is wrong:

```
Customer customer = gson.fromJson(settings.getCustomerObjectJSONString(), Customer.class);
```

I would like for it to just skip the field that it cannot parse, because I don't have access to the Customer class, as it is from a generated SDK/library.

Comment: how looks the wrong type? can you put some example data? also will be great expected and obtained result

Comment: I have attached the wrong type and expected result. But the issue is something I would like to have a generalized solution for.

Comment: You can write your custom [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) where you can implement more complex parsing rules.

Comment: How would that look?

Comment: please, add also some code to see how you deserialize

Comment: also, [`Date(number)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) can be correct....

Comment: I have updated the question with more info and a line of code that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware of two options.

You can use **a JSON deserializer** implementation to parse JSON elements on your own. However the following example would affect ALL `double` and `Double` fields for whatever DTOs passed to that single `gson` instance, and such a behavior can be deseriable. Unfortunately, I don't know if it's possible to use `JsonDeserializer` in a "context" way: e.g. let it work for all `double` and `Double` fields if those are fields of a certain parent class.

```java
private static final class Dto {

    private double primitive;
    private Double nullable;
    private String string;

}

private static final class FailSafeDoubleJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(final JsonElement element, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        if ( !element.isJsonPrimitive() ) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            final JsonPrimitive primitive = (JsonPrimitive) element;
            final Number number = primitive.getAsNumber();
            return number.doubleValue();
        } catch ( final NumberFormatException ignored ) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}

private static final JsonDeserializer<Double> failSafeDoubleJsonDeserializer = new FailSafeDoubleJsonDeserializer();

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(double.class, failSafeDoubleJsonDeserializer)
        .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, failSafeDoubleJsonDeserializer)
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    dump(gson.fromJson("{\"primitive\": 23, \"nullable\": 42, \"string\": \"foo bar\"}", Dto.class));
    dump(gson.fromJson("{\"primitive\": \"whatever\", \"nullable\": \"whatever\", \"string\": \"foo bar\"}", Dto.class));
}

private static void dump(final Dto dto) {
    out.println(dto.primitive + " " + dto.nullable + " " + dto.string);
}
```

Another more low level option can be **a type adapter** implementation. One advantage of this one over the previous example is that you can annotate failing fields with the `@JsonAdapter` annotation in DTO classes that are known to be potentially broken.

```java
private static final class Dto {

    @JsonAdapter(FailSafeDoubleTypeAdapter.class)
    private double primitive;

    @JsonAdapter(FailSafeDoubleTypeAdapter.class)
    private Double nullable;

    private String string;

}

private static final class FailSafeDoubleTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Double> {

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter writer, final Double value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Double read(final JsonReader reader)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken peek = reader.peek();
        if ( peek != NUMBER ) {
            reader.skipValue();
            return null;
        }
        return reader.nextDouble();
    }

}

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    dump(gson.fromJson("{\"primitive\": 23, \"nullable\": 42, \"string\": \"foo bar\"}", Dto.class));
    dump(gson.fromJson("{\"primitive\": \"whatever\", \"nullable\": {\"subValue\": \"whatever\"}, \"string\": \"foo bar\"}", Dto.class));
}

private static void dump(final Dto dto) {
    out.println(dto.primitive + " " + dto.nullable + " " + dto.string);
}
```

Thus, both examples generate the following output:

> 23.0 42.0 foo bar
>
> 0.0 null foo bar

for

- `{"primitive": 23, "nullable": 42, "string": "foo bar"}`
- and `{"primitive": "whatever", "nullable": {"subValue": "whatever"}, "string": "foo bar"}`

payloads respectively.

Comment: I will analyze the answer! Thank you

Comment: @AndreasRudolph I tried to re-implement it in a more robust way, but I couldn't make it better. If you cannot change the generated code, you might probably want either bloat your types with DTOs where your DTOs could be parsing-error-friendly (say, your DTO then might have an `Object` field that could be converted to anything) -- not a very good way; or use separate `Gson` instances with different deserialization strategies (say, just override `double` fields deserialiation for your "bad" class) -- a bad advice too, unfortunately. Or maybe take a deeper look at `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the problem in another perspective i.e. the main requirement mentioned in the OP is

1) You don't care what value present in a particular field

2) You are not going to use the particular field value, and don't want the deserializer to fail because of invalid data

In the above case, you can mark the particular field as TRANSIENT or STATIC. By default, Gson will exclude all fields marked transient or static.

**Example:-**

```
private transient Date joiningDate;
```

Comment: As I said, I can't access the field without a lot of hassle, because it is from a generated library/SDK. But thank you!